# Dynamic initializer with protocol

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm working with `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON`. I want to build general request and parse model for common situations. Firstly, I make a protocol called `JSONConvertible`.

```
protocol JSONConvertible {
    init?(json: JSON)
}
```

Secondly, I extend `Request` class in `Alamofire`.

```
extension Request {

    func getResult(format: [String: AnyClass]) {
        self.responseJSON { (response) in
            guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else {
                return
            }
            switch statusCode {
            case 200:
                var result = [String: AnyObject]()
                let json = JSON(rawValue: response.result.value!)!
                for (key, className) in format {
                    if className.self is JSONConvertible {
                        let value = className.self(json: json[key]) // get error in this line
                    }
                }
            case 201..<400:
                break
            case 400...Int.max:
                break
            default:
                break
            }

        }
    }   
}
```

But I get an error from the compiler. Because AnyObject is only protocol and it doesn't have this initializer. I don't want get a dictionary or array only. I want to get instances with concrete class. Please help me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because inside the `if` the type for `className.self` is still `AnyObject`. You need to cast it to `JSONConvertible` and then can use the initializer.

```
if let concreteClass = className.self as? JSONConvertible.Type 
{
   let value = concreteClass.init(json: json[key])
}
```

If you are familiar with kotlin, swift doesn't do casting automatically when testing for type in an `if` clause.

Comment: At least no error any more. Thanks! I will test if it will work.

Comment: Note you don't need the `.self` – `className as? JSONConvertible.Type` will do.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve this. Define a new protocol.

```
protocol JSONConvertibleObject: AnyObject, JSONConvertible {

}
```

And use this instead.

```
extension Request {

    func getResult(format: [String: JSONConvertibleObject]) {
        self.responseJSON { (response) in
            guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else {
                return
            }
            switch statusCode {
            case 200:
                var result = [String: AnyObject]()
                let json = JSON(rawValue: response.result.value!)!
                for (key, className) in format {
                    let value = className.self.dynamicType.init(json: json[key])
                }
            case 201..<400:
                break
            case 400...Int.max:
                break
            default:
                break
            }

        }
    }   
}
```